# clearInterval in webworker is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webworker and its working fine.

webworker.js :

```
//portion of webworker.js
self.onmessage = function(evt){
    if(evt.data == "start"){
      var i = 0;
      var mytimer = setInterval(function(){
            i++;
            postMessage(i);
      },1000);
    }

    if(evt.data == "stop"){
       clearInterval(mytimer);
    }

}
```

but clear interval is not working. Am i missing something?

Comment: Remove the `var` part before the mytimer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mytimer` is local to your function. If you want it to persist across calls to `onmessage`, you need to move it to some outer scope:

```
var mytimer;

self.onmessage = function(evt) {
    if (evt.data == "start") {
        var i = 0;

        mytimer = setInterval(function() {
            i++;
            postMessage(i);
        }, 1000);
    } else if (evt.data == "stop") {
        clearInterval(mytimer);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the problem is with the scope of the `mytimer` variable.

If you want to avoid cluttering up the global namespace, you could store it as a static variable using [this hack](http://javascript.info/tutorial/static-variables-methods-decorators):

```
self.onmessage = function(evt){
    if(evt.data == "start"){
      var i = 0;
      arguments.callee.mytimer = setInterval(function(){
            i++;
            postMessage(i);
      },1000);
    }

    if(evt.data == "stop"){
       clearInterval(arguments.callee.mytimer);
    }

}
```

Comment: That’s not very clean. Given support for web workers, can’t you at least use a named function?