# clearInterval in web worker not stopping timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, countdown, web-worker

my question has been asked once here:
[clearInterval in webworker is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110289/clearinterval-in-webworker-is-not-working)

The solution seems clear but for some reason it is not working for me yet. I have a web worker that is sending an interval back to the main thread. I want to be able to stop the interval with clearInterval, but it is not working.

I have it set up exactly the same as it suggests in the previous question, but still no luck. I have added some console.logs to verify I'm in the correct block. "Stop" logs to the console when it supposed to, but the timer doesn't stop posting to the main thread.

Can anyone spot what's going on here?

Thanks

worker.js

```
let mytimer;

self.onmessage = function(evt) {
    if (evt.data == "start") {
        console.log("start")
        var i = 0;
        
        mytimer = setInterval(function() {
            i++;
            postMessage(i);
        }, 1000);
        
    } else if (evt.data == "stop") {
        console.log("stop")

        clearInterval(mytimer);
    }
};
```

Then I'm calling this from my React hook when timer.time is above or below a certain value (2000 in this case)

main.js

```
  const worker = new myWorker()

 useEffect(() => {

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

      //from interval in the worker
      console.log('Message from Worker: ' + e.data);
    })

    if(timer.time > 2000){
      worker.postMessage("start")
    }else{

      worker.postMessage("stop")
    }
  },[timer.time])
```

Comment: How are you creating the worker instance?

Comment: right above useEffect with   const worker = new myWorker()

Comment: I think that is the problem, every time the component is updated, a new worker instance is created. try to store the worker in useRef: const worker = useRef(new myWorker()).

Comment: oh, that's smart. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also clear the interval when you start a new interval. If you don't do it, your previous interval would keep running, and you'll lose the ability to clear it:

```
let mytimer;

self.onmessage = function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.data)
  
  if(evt.data === 'start' || evt.data === 'stop') {
    clearInterval(mytimer);
  }

  if (evt.data == "start") {
    var i = 0;

    mytimer = setInterval(function() {
      i++;
      postMessage(i);
    }, 1000);

  }
};
```

You should create a single instance of the worker, and store it as ref:

```
const worker = useRef()

useEffect(() => {
  worker.current = new myWorker()

  return () => {
    worker.current.terminate();
  }
}, [])
```

Not related, but in addition, the `useEffect` adds a new event listener whenever `timer.time` changes, without clearing the previous one. I would split this into 2 `useEffect` blocks, one for sending (which can be combind with the creation of the worker), and the other for receiving.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const eventHander = e => {
    //from interval in the worker
    console.log('Message from Worker: ' + e.data);
  }

  worker.current.addEventListener('message', eventHander)
  
  return () => {
    worker.current.removeEventListener('message', eventHander)
  }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  worker.current.postMessage(timer.time > 2000 ? 'start' : 'stop')
}, [timer.time])
```

Comment: thanks, I actually tried this previously. I just added clearInterval right before setting the interval, but it's still not stopping. I tried your way too just now, and still no luck. It might be the useEffect problem.

Comment: brilliant, could I invite you to check out my other related (and slightly more detailed) question related to this topic? here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703264/how-to-move-react-countdown-timer-to-worker-thread

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about web workers but I am very familiar with using intervals in `useEffect`. Since `useEffect` is called everytime your dependencies change (`timer.time`), you need to store the interval in a useRef unless you are going to be clearing it before your dependency next changes

Comment: hmm, I'm not exactly sure if that applies bc my interval is in the worker. I'm not sure I fully understand though, either :/

Comment: If it is declared in the worker which is being declared in useEffect, than it is being declared in useEffect I believe. (Not 100% sure though without looking at the worker source and seeing where you are storing the worker) .  Try using useRef and ref.current whenver you set and clear it and see if it resolves it. Worth a try anyways.